# We say entrepreneur and entrepreneurship, what is the verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, adverbs

For the word entrepreneur and entrepreneurship, I would like to know the corresponding verb, i.e the action of doing entrepreneurship, i.e the verb that should fit in the next sentence :

`To be a good entrepreneur you should ________ this and that project`.

What would be the verb that shares the same root ? entrep... ??

Comment: Entrepreneuring is a word. You can't use it in conjunction with project though.

Comment: The verb is *entreprendre,* and was not borrowed from French. Maybe the verb should be *entreprend*. It would fit the model of *attendre/attend*.

Comment: That what I was trying to refer to, I avoid it to not get my question closed, now I get it all thx

Comment: We have ***comedian/comic*** and ***comedy***, but so far as I know, there's no verb based on that root for *doing* the activity. And why should there be?

Comment: Enterprising is used as an adjective, but unfortunately doesn't seem to correspond to a verb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can **undertake** the project.
(Or **take** it **up**. Gotta love idiom, no?)
You can **embark on** a project, you can simply **do** a project.

Actually, an undertaking is a synonym for a project.

The strange thing is that the noun "undertaker" has gotten the specific meaning in English of a person that buries dead people - hence the use of the French for the professional.

This is a common source for (embarrassing) mistakes by foreigners. For a Dutchman for instance, it makes no sense consider that *onder* means *under* and *nemen* mean *to take*:

> Onderneming -> undertaking (though it can also mean enterprise - same French source!)
>   Ondernemen -> to undertake
>   Ondernemer -> undertaker -> entrepreneur.

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact verb for entrepreneur. Entrepreneurial is an adjective, and the two you listed, but no verb.

There's many verbs that could fit your blank: lead, command, undertake, drive, organize, manage, etc.

Comment: See Peter Shor's comment above for the verb for entrepreneur.  Please cite your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **launch** because it correlates to starting something up.  When you start something you have to at some point launch (e.g. publish, release, deliver), then begins the cycle of shipping (e.g. to the value stream).

Launching seems to have the connotation of monetization baked in and that's an important distinction for entrepreneurs.

"I'm launching a venture to create plant-fueled cars."

Or, if you don't like "launch" I'd go with "starting" which relates to startups.

"I'm starting a company to create plant-fueled cars."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think, 'venture' could be the verb to be used here. Connotatively, they are close enough.

Comment: **Venture** as a verb would not fit in the given statement.

Comment: I was looking for a verb with same root, like "Entreprendre" in French for exemple, venture is a whole other thing.

Answer (score -1):

We can use *embark [on a business venture]*. The process can be called entrepreneurship, and the person can be addressed as *entrepreneur*.

Comment: But is it okay to use _entrepreneur_ (or some altered form of that word) as a verb? That appears to be the gist of the poster's question.